# How to get titles(a row in a table) from MySql database so that the titles are in a particular order

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT id,title,image,address,serviceType FROM `ta` ORDER BY title LIMIT 0,20
```

It gives me results based on ordering of the titles.

The default ordering puts **'titles'** starting with special characters first, then titles starting with numbers and then titles starting with alphabets.

But I want, first titles starting with numbers, then titles starting with alphabets and then titles starting with special characters.

Please help.

Comment: "Starting with alphabets" doesn't make sense. Do you mean "starting with numbers"?

Comment: Sorry, edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can put case statement in your order by clause. Somthing like this:-

```
SELECT id, title, image, address, serviceType 
FROM `ta` 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN title LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN 1
              WHEN title LIKE '[A-Z]%' THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END
LIMIT 0,20
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Ankit Bajpai: What does 1 and 2 mean here?

Comment: 1 and 2 means order. It means digits first, then alphabets etc. Can you plz share the error you got.

Comment: I got the following error in MySQL database:`code #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN title LIKE '[A-Z]%' THEN 2 END ELSE title END LIMIT 0,20' at line 4`

Answer (score 0):

How to ask a question:

Hello, I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE strings
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,string VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO strings (string) VALUES 
('apple'),
('banana'),
('cherry'),
('*durian'),
('1eggplant'),
('10fig'),
('grapefruit');


SELECT * FROM strings;
+----+------------+
| id | string     |
+----+------------+
|  4 | *durian    |
|  6 | 10fig      |
|  5 | 1eggplant  |
|  1 | apple      |
|  2 | banana     |
|  3 | cherry     |
|  7 | grapefruit |
+----+------------+
```

I would like a result set like this...

[PUT YOUR DESIRED OUTPUT HERE]

... where the rows are arranged by x, y z.

I tried this...

[PUT YOUR BEST EFFORT HERE]

... but that's not right because it's wrong in the following ways...